# C++ initialization of automatics and scope

Tags: c++, initialization, scope

Can anyone point me to a reference in the C++ standard that guarantees me that the automatic *char** *q* in the function *foo1()* will always be initialized after *p = bar()* has been called in *foo1()*. I am so used to creating a new block like in *foo2()* and am wondering if I am being overly blockish and paranoid of the optimizing compiler. Or I am correct in being paranoid and should not assume that the compiler will not optimize the code such that *p = bar()* will always be called before *q(p)*?
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>


char* bar()
{
    char* t = (char*)malloc(15);
    strcpy(t, "Hello World!");
    return t;
}

void foo1(void)
{
    char* p = NULL;

    printf("foo1: do some stuff\n");

    p = bar();

    printf("foo1: do some more stuff\n");

    char* q(p);

    printf("foo1: q says:%s\n", q);

    free(p);
}

void foo2(void)
{
    char* p = NULL;

    printf("foo2: do some stuff\n");

    p = bar();

    printf("foo2: do some more stuff\n");

    // is this block necessary?
    {
        char* q(p);

        printf("foo2: q says:%s\n", q);
    }

    free(p);
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    foo1();
    foo2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow- can you say "Horrific C code posing as C++"?

Comment: I can't point to a specific part of the standard at the moment, but they key phrase to look for is *sequence point*.

Comment: @Steve I prefer to write `char* q = p;` to `char* q(p);`, so that one don't confuse with `q` is a function taking a parameter of type `p` and returns a `char*`.

Comment: @Steve: For the sake of humanity please use `std::string`. There's no reason to be using manually managing memory via `malloc()`/`free()` all the time in C++ like you have now. http://tinyurl.com/dont-use-pointers

Comment: @DeadMG,  and Mahesh, and tiny: I deeply apologize for using 'C' code as C++ to present the issue. Some 'C' compilers will compile this, some won't. So far all C++ compilers that I have tried will. I could not think of an easier way to communicate the problem in less LOC. Thanks for the on-topic replies.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely assume that `p = bar()` will occur before `char * q(p)` due to the existence of [*sequence points*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

I can't bring myself to wade through the C++ standard right now, but I can give you the equivalent from the C99 standard, which I hope will put your mind at ease sufficiently:

**5.1.2.3:**

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of
>   the execution environment. Evaluation of an expression may produce side effects. At
>   certain specified points in the execution sequence called sequence points, all side effects
>   of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations
>   shall have taken place.

**Annex C:** *(emphasis mine)*

> The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>
> - The call
>     to a function, after the arguments have been evaluated.
> - The end of the first operand of the following operators: logical AND
>     `&&`; logical OR `||`; conditional `?`; comma `,`.
> - The end of a full declarator;
> - The
>     end of a full expression: **an initializer**; the expression in an
>     expression statement; the controlling expression of a
>     selection statement (`if` or `switch`); the controlling expression
>     of a `while` or `do` statement; each of the expressions of a `for`
>     statement; the expression in a `return` statement.
> - Immediately before a library function returns.
> - After the
>     actions associated with each formatted input/output function
>     conversion specifier.
> - Immediately before and
>     immediately after each call to a comparison function, and also between
>     any call to a comparison function and any movement of the objects
>     passed as arguments to that call.

Comment: C++11 discards sequence points for 'sequenced before' and 'sequenced after' I think.

Comment: @bames53 : Indeed it does, but only the wording changed -- the semantics were intended to remain the same as C++03, only with clearer wording.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be this paranoid. C++ says

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a
>   full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.
>
> **[intro.execution] 1.9 /14 ,n3337**

Comment: +1 for a correct answer. but why are you quoting N3337. i mean, N3290 is the same as the current standard (C++11), while N3337 is the first draft of the next standard?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : N3290 has not been freely available for quite some time; perhaps bames simply doesn't have a copy?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf n3337 is the first post-C++11 draft of the standard. It has all the content of the published C++11 standard but with some typos and the like fixed.

Answer (score 0):

C++03 6.7/2 "Declaration statement" says:

> Variables with automatic storage duration (3.7.2) are initialized each time their declaration-statement is executed.  Variables with automatic storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the block